# Many folders project Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following project structure:

```
common
|-- foo.cpp
|-- foo.h
exercise_1
|-- main.cpp
|-- bar_1.cpp
|-- bar_1.h
exercise_2
|-- main.cpp
|-- bar_2.cpp
|-- bar_2.h
...
```

How can one organize `Makefile` to build such project from the main directory e.g.:

```
make exercise_10
```

So that this command would build object files in `common` directory, in `exercise_10` folder and link them all to executable in `exercise_10`. I started with the following:

```
COMPILER = g++
INCLUDE = -I common/
DEPS = common/*.o

OBJECTS := $(patsubst common/%.cpp, common/%.o, $(wildcard common/*.cpp))

common: $(OBJECTS)

exercise_%:
    $(COMPILER) $@/main.cpp $(INCLUDE) -o $@/main $(DEPS)
```

But it's not working and I don't know what to do next.

Thanks!

Comment: An indirect way that could help is to use an IDE such as Netbeans (version 8.2) for C++ on linux. Then, you are able to set up your project / folders the way you want graphically and intuitively and then the IDE automatically generates the makefile for you, however complicated the structure. Then, once you are comfortable with this setting, you can copy over the makefiles making changes to the files depending on the name of the .cpp file. Netbeans, for instance, creates a series of files Makefile, Makefile-Debug, Makefile-Release, .dep.inc on its own once you use its IDE to setup the project.

Comment: Is having rules like `exercise_10/exercise_10.exe: exercise_10/main.o common/foo.o`, calling with `make exercise_10/exercise_10.exe` good enough? If not I'd consider making a shell wrapper. Make is for making files from files, everything else gets weird.

Comment: It would help a lot if you defined what "it's not working" actually means.  What exactly happens when you try to run `make exercise_10`?  How can we provide answers when you haven't given any details on the problem?  One thing I will say is that you have defined the object files in `common`, but in your link line for building individual exercises you don't reference those objects.

Comment: This is true, I also at some point wrote a shell script, though wanted to know a bit more about Makefile.

Comment: Don't use `COMPILER`.  By long standing convention, the variable name for the C compiler is `CC` and the variable used for the the C++ compiler is `CXX`.  `PC` for pascal, `FC` for fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GNU make you could define a macro to build any of your exercises. Something like the following:

```
EXERCISES      := $(wildcard exercise_*)
MAINS          := $(addsuffix /main,$(EXERCISES))

.PHONY: all
all: $(MAINS)

common-objs    := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard common/*.cpp))
common-headers := $(wildcard common/*.h)

%.o: %.cpp $(common-headers)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -Icommon -c $< -o $@

# $(1): exercise directory
define BUILD_EXERCISE
.PHONY: $(1)

$(1): $(1)/main

$(1)-objs    := $$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$$(wildcard $(1)/*.cpp))
OBJS         += $$($(1)-objs)
$(1)-headers := $$(wildcard $(1)/*.h)

$$($(1)-objs): $$($(1)-headers)

$(1)/main: $$($(1)-objs) $$(common-objs)
    $$(CXX) $$(CXXFLAGS) $$(LDFLAGS) -o $$@ $$^ $$(LDLIBS)
endef
$(foreach e,$(EXERCISES),$(eval $(call BUILD_EXERCISE,$(e))))

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(MAINS) $(OBJS) $(common-objs)
```

It looks a bit complicated but it's not. The only trick is the `$$` in the `BUILD_EXERCISE` macro. It is needed because the macro is expanded twice by make. Everything else is straightforward:

- `CXX`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` are [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables).
- `$@`, `$<` and `$^` are [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).
- `wildcard`, `addsuffix`, `patsubst`, `foreach`, `eval` and `call` are [make functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Functions).
- [Phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) are declared as prerequisites of the `.PHONY` special target.
- [The `foreach-eval-call` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) is a way to programmatically instantiate make statements.
- `%.o: %.cpp...` is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules).

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks scary, but it works exactly in the way it supposed to! Though I feel bad since I understand a little from it)

Comment: @Denisof If you really need/want to understand just follow the links. In less than an hour you'll have a much better understanding of GNU make. And this will not be a waste of time if you frequently write makefiles.